# InDesign CC2019 Extension - Chromium shows "Caution provisional headers are shown" message

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm writing an InDesign Extension, InDesign has a embedded chromium (Version  61.0.3163.91) and we're displaying a vaadin website.

Works for previous InDesign CC Versions, but not for the new CC2019. In this version we don't see the content of the page, but this "Caution provisional headers are shown" messages in the debugger.

I can use Chrome as a remote debugger for InDesign so I can see the console, network and more.

In the 'network' I see for every request a Status '200 OK' and the 'Provisional headers are shown' message. I see the correct response and preview for the requests - I do not see the final page.

[image: chrome screenshot 1]

This is for all request - html, css, javascript, json, images.

I searched stackoverflow for this message and I found some threads and I tried all tipps and ideas in the answers - nothing helped.

When I use the same URL in my chrome browser it works fine. So it may be a problem with this chromium version. Unfortunately I can't just update Chromium because it's embedded in InDesign.

So at the moment I'm out of ideas how to solve this - does anybody has a tipp for me?